# is new myObject().Load(); okay?

Tags: c#, .net

Can i just do this:

```
private someMethodSomewhere(){
    new myObject().Load();
}
```

Instead of this:

```
private someMethodSomewhere(){
    myObject objectItem = new myObject().Load();
}
```

**Is it the same thing?**

---

**EDIT:**
I didn't think this needed clarification... but i guess it does:
Load() DOES return an instance of myObject.... otherwise it would not compile.

Comment: I assume you mean `myObject objectItem = new myObject(); objectItem.Load();`?

Comment: Why do you call a method on an object you don't use? In that case, you could make your method static and only call it on the class like MyClass.Load() without having to create a new instance of an object.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Who knows what `Load()` returns?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft : no i meant what i put. if both items i put are the same then it's the same to what you put, then it's all the same.

Comment: @StevenGilligan : because i don't want to have to worry about locking writable variables, helps with unit testing, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! If that's exactly the code you're using, then it is the same thing.

Comment: I have to give it to you. Not only were you first, I just needed a yes or a no. I appreciate your straight forwardness. @sixlettervariables ofcourse `Load()` returns instance of `myObject` the code would not compile otherwise.

Comment: @capdragon: "ofcourse `Load()` returns...", considering your question code does not compile, I seriously doubted it did.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Actually, it will compile if it's a constructor.

Comment: @minitech: oddly named class, but touche.

Answer (score 3):

The following are equivalent:

```
private someMethodSomewhere(){
    new myObject().Load();
}
```

and:

```
private someMethodSomewhere(){
    myObject objectItem = new myObject();
    objectItem.Load();
}
```

Your second snippet probably won't compile unless the `Load` method returns an instance of `myObject`.

And if `Load` returns an instance of `myObject` then the following is the same:

```
private someMethodSomewhere() {
    myObject objectItem = new myObject().Load();
}
```

When you compile in Release mode the compiler will probably optimize it anyway and remove the unused `objectItem` variable and both will end up as:

```
private someMethodSomewhere() {
    new myObject().Load();
}
```

in the final IL.

Comment: If `Load()` returns an instance of `myObject`, I can't see any reason why it wouldn't compile. Unless C# and Java are considerably more different than I remember...

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, that's why I said `won't compile unless the Load method returns an instance of myObject`.

Comment: That wasn't in the answer when I wrote my comment. Your edit seems to have addressed that point, however.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same thing unless you don't want to use `objectitem` inside your method. 
From functional point of view, there is no any difference.

**EDIT**

Correct code in second case would be

```
private someMethodSomewhere(){
    myObject objectItem = new myObject();
    objectItem.Load();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but in the first example you aren't assigning the new object to a variable and can't do nothing with it. A better way to do this is:

```
private someMethodSomewhere(){
    myObject objectItem = new myObject();
    objectItem.Load();
}
```